# GPAY option not showing on chrome browser on Windows

Tags: javascript, asp.net, stripe-payments, google-pay

I have integrated stripe payment gateway in one of my applications. I am able to see the GPAY option on Android mobile but I am not able to see the GPAY option in Windows chrome or IOS chrome browser. And also getting this error **Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'ch-ua-form-factor'.**

The error is only coming on Windows and IOS chrome browsers.

Please advice me on the issue.

Please let me know whether GPAY option will be supported other than Android devices when integrating with stripe.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test Google Pay with Stripe you need to have:

- Chrome 61 or newer
- An activated [Google Pay card](https://payments.google.com/gp/w/home/paymentmethods)
- HTTPS endpoint to your web application
- [Not being in India](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#apple-pay-and-google-pay:%7E:text=Stripe%20Elements%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20support%20Google%20Pay%20or%20Apple%20Pay%20for%20Stripe%20accounts%20and%20customers%20in%20India.%20Therefore%2C%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20test%20your%20Google%20Pay%20or%20Apple%20Pay%20integration%20if%20the%20tester%E2%80%99s%20IP%20address%20is%20in%20India%2C%20even%20if%20the%20Stripe%20account%20is%20based%20outside%20India.)

Comment: Thanks for the response . But I am able see the same in Android device even with India's IP address .

Comment: @Somunath could you create a reproducer and share it here?